# How to handle new values in prediction data when predicting on an existing Model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a model trained and I am calling that to predict on new data. How should I handle the data to be predicted if it has new values in it which was not there in the data that was used to train the model?

Comment: Could you give an example? I assume it's something like you have a feature that was learned with either A, B or C and you try to predict a new sample that has D for this feature?

Comment: Yes.Exactly.So should i retrain the model everytime there are new values or is there any other way around that?